# Wondering about the theme change?

Tags: discussion

[Responsive design released for all Beta & Undesigned sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315662/responsive-design-released-for-all-beta-undesigned-sites?cb=1)

This is a new responsive theme that has been rolled out. If you have problems, or want to adjust some of your preferences (Such as collapsing the left menu), there are instructions and linked posts in the MSE post linked above.